# Flex Slider Left and Right Arrow Limitation

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, flexslider

Am using flexslider to show images with right and left arrow icons. It is working fine with left and right icons in my application. My Problem is, when i have one image then also it is shows me left and right icons which is not required as per client request. Can you please help me out.

Here is flexslider code:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('.flexslider').flexslider({
        animation: "slide",
        animationLoop: false,
        itemWidth: 75,
        itemMargin: 5,
        reverse: false,
        move:1,
        slideshow: false,
        controlNav: false,
        directionNav: true,
        prevText: "Previous",
        nextText: "Next",
        start: function(slider){
            $('body').removeClass('loading');
            $('.flexslider').resize();
        },
        end: function(slider){
            slider.flexAnimate(0);
        }
    });
})
```

Please tell me the changes where I have to change.
Thank you.

Comment: If by right and left icons you mean the left and right navigation arrows then you should check with JavaScript or jQuery how many slides you have and if slidesNumber == 1 then hide navigation arrows.

Comment: Or try this: ```allowOneSlide: {new}

Boolean. Whether or not you'd like FlexSlider to initialize as usual if only one slide is present.``` Flexslider documentation: https://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider

Answer (score 2):

Try using:

```
$('.flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: slide,
    smoothHeight: true,
    itemWidth: "100%",
    slideshowSpeed: 6000,
    pauseOnHover:true,
    directionNav:true,
    prevText: "Previous",
    nextText: "Next",
    start: function(slider){
         $('body').removeClass('loading');
         $('.flexslider').resize();
    },
     end: function(slider){
         slider.flexAnimate( 0 );
     }      
});
```

Hope that helps..

Comment: Same thing I have used and it is working for me.. This is the reason why I gave you this solution. Since I have tested this first on my web page.

Comment: Hi Yunus, am using left and right arrows with images not an icons.